# General Linear Mixed Models

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, survival, relative-risk

I'm trying to model excess mortality of cancer patients, and am currently using a general linear model following a poisson distribution. However, I haven't allowed for the possibility that people develop second primary cancers after a first cancer. Obviously these people have a different mortality pattern than people with only one cancer, so this needs to be allowed for. I need to be able to model this conditionally, such that when you put inputs into the equation it will be variables at diagnosis for the the first cancer (e.g. stage), and then a variable to represent if they have had another cancer after surviving a given duration.

I am a SAS user and have seen that general linear mixed models might be a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a measure of time in your data? Meaning if you know how long each patient stays in your dataset, and how long after the first cancer the second appears per patient?